# im getting a error while inserting as Failure 1 (near "0": syntax error) on 0x1f1700 when preparing 'CREATE TABLE Project_Details

Tags: android, sqlite

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String ProjectDetailTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PROJECT_DETAIL  + "("
            + ProjectID  + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + ProjectName + " VARCHAR," + Budget + " VARCHAR," + Duration + " VARCHAR," + StartDate+ " VARCHAR," + ProjectDescription+ " VARCHAR)";

    String ExpensesTable = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PROJECT_EXPENSES + "("+ExpensesID+"INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ExpProjectName+"VARCHAR," 
                +Date +"VARCHAR,"+ExpensesTitle+"VARCHAR,"+ExpensesAmount+"VARCHAR,"+ExpDescription+"VARCHAR)";
      db.execSQL(ProjectDetailTable);
      db.execSQL(ExpensesTable);



}
```

Comment: Can you print the string you're producing?

Comment: There is no space in second query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add space between `Column Name` and `Column Type`

```
 String ExpensesTable = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PROJECT_EXPENSES + "("+ExpensesID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ExpProjectName+" VARCHAR," 
            +Date +" VARCHAR,"+ExpensesTitle+" VARCHAR,"+ExpensesAmount+" VARCHAR,"+ExpDescription+" VARCHAR)";
```

Comment: Fastest gun in the West! +1.

Comment: @Manish, similar answer. but you were faster :D

Answer (score 0):

Add spaces in the second query between field name and field type.

```
String ExpensesTable = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PROJECT_EXPENSES + " ( "+ExpensesID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ExpProjectName+" VARCHAR," 
                +Date +" VARCHAR,"+ExpensesTitle+" VARCHAR,"+ExpensesAmount+" VARCHAR,"+ExpDescription+" VARCHAR)";
```